# Why doesnt the color not show on my character model?

Tags: texturing, uv

Im new to blender and I first want to clarify that, because I wont be able to describe somethings properly, anyways heres the problem, I was trying to add one basic color to my character model using uv mapping just to start things off, I press "ALT Z" but the color wont show.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you defined a material for your model? Also please indicate which rendering engine you are using (Blender internal, Cycles) as the material setup depends on it.

Comment: Im using cycles, also yes I have defined a material im pretty sure.

Comment: You should upload your file using this link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so someone here can have a look and help for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm there is no material defined for your model.

Here is the way to create it and assign the texture:

[image]

- Go to the material tab
- Create a new material
- Change the color, indicating you want an image texture
- Choose the image
- Then you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle the 3D view to rendering mode (you can also use material or texture modes).

The created material can also be defined using the Cycles nodes system (both UI does the same, but nodes is more clear if your material becomes complex):

[image]

- Create the material
- Open a node view
- Choose material nodes: by default a simple diffuse setting is created
- Add <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> an image texture node
- Connect it to the diffuse color
- Select the wanted image